# Como fazer uma busca no DB Redis passando o filtro *?

Tags: laravel, cache, redis

Tenho projeto Laravel, e estou usando o Redis com o Predis. Para buscar o valor de uma chave uso o `Cache::get('chave:id:outro')` e isso me retorna o valor.
Mas como fazer para buscar varios valores da mesma chave parcial com o predis?
Não funciona apenas `Cache::get('chave:*')`. Qual seria outra opção?

Answer (score -2):

A Facade Cache do laravel não tem essa função. Eles até tem uma função de tags, mas não dá de trazer os dados com essas tags, só serve pra excluir em massa os dados marcados com essa tags.

Para realizar uma busca de chaves no redis, podemos usar a Facade do Redis:

```
//retorna todos as chaves em um array ou null
$keysInCache = Redis::keys('*');
```

Pode ser usado para pesquisar um padrão de chaves:

```
//retorna todos as chaves com o padrão em um array ou null
$keysInCache = Redis::keys('padrao:de:chaves:*');
```

Se você tiver uma conexão específica no seu database.php, pode fazer assim:

```
$keysInCache = Redis::connection('nome_da_conexao')->keys('padrao:de:chaves');
```

E se quiser trazer todos os valores, pode passar o array de chaves que a função keys retorna:

```
$keysInCache = Redis::keys('*');

$valuesInCache = $Redis::mget($keysInCache);
```

Praticamente todas as funções que tem no Redis-cli, também tem na facade do Redis.